# if jQuery element hasClass() change different element link text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using a jQuery function to add/remove a class to the clicked element, which works just fine. However when that element is clicked, I am trying to change the text of an HTML link and I cannot seem to get it working. The HTML link is located within the `<span>` element further down the page.

When `<button id="people">` hasClass('user_view_active') the HTML link should display "People" when `<button id="jobs">` hasClass('user_view_active') the HTML link should display "Jobs".

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function() {
        $('button').click(function(){
            $('button').each(function(){
                $(this).removeClass('user_view_active'); 
            });
        $(this).addClass('user_view_active');
        });

        if ($('#people').hasClass('user_view_active')){
            $('.title').find("a").attr("href").text(text.replace('People'));
        }else{
            $('.title').find("a").attr("href").text(text.replace('Jobs'));
        }
    });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="container">

    <header>
            <img src="images/header-name.png" width="200px" style="display: inline; margin-bottom: -10px;"/>
            <button id="jobs" class="user_view"><a href="#">Jobs</a></button> 
            <button id="people" class="user_view_active user_view"><a href="#">People</a></button>

            <div class="header_search_wrapper">
                <form action="" method="POST">
                    <textarea class="header_search" name="app_search" placeholder="Search people, jobs, or companies" style="width: 430px;"></textarea>

                    <input type="submit" class="share_btn" value="Search">
                </form>
            </div>
    </header>

    <div id="main" role="main">
        <!--! begin app content -->

        <div class="right_sidebar">
        <span class="right_title">Connection Suggestions</title>


        </div>

        <span class="title">Recent Updates >> <a href="#">People</a></span>
```

Comment: There is already an answer that should help you, but also there is no need to `.each` over the collection of buttons to remove the class from each one. Just do `$('button').removeClass('user_view_active');` and it will remove the class from all of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To replace the text within a link you can use the [jQuery `.text()` function](http://api.jquery.com/text/).  This function can also get the text value and also set the text value - as is shown in the example below -

```
if ($('#people').hasClass('user_view_active')){
  $('.title').find("a").text('People'); 
}else{
  $('.title').find("a").text('Jobs'); 
}
```

This code would have to be wrapped in the callback function of the click event to work -

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button').click(function(){
    $('button').removeClass('user_view_active'); 
    $(this).addClass('user_view_active');
    if ($('#people').hasClass('user_view_active')){
      $('.title').find("a").text('People');
    }else{
      $('.title').find("a").text('Jobs');
    }
  });
});
```

Now each time the button is clicked, you can check for the existence of the `user_view_active` class on the `#people` element.

Comment: theres an extra ; here i think `$('.title').find("a").text('Jobs');;`

Comment: @HastigZusammenstellen - true true - thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 1):

Okeydokey ?

Are you sure those are the right tags ?

```
<span class="right_title">Connection Suggestions</title>
```

Are you sure an `<a>` element inside a `<button>` element is a good idea?

```
<button id="jobs" class="user_view"><a href="#">Jobs</a></button>
```

`role="main"` is'nt a valid attribute, but will probably work anyway.

This just seems easier:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('button').on('click', function(){
        $('button').removeClass('user_view_active');; 
        $(this).addClass('user_view_active');
        $("a", ".title").text(this.id);
    });
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8uWzg/1/)

Comment: I have a JS function that will set set the attribute "role" so that is taken care of. And you are correct, using an <a> element in a button is not a good idea, I changed it to respond with onclick(). Thank you for catching that.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way:**

```
$('#people').toggleClass('user_view_active').html($('#people').hasClass('user_view_active')?'People':'Jobs');
```