# jQuery: if (dd).class = active then (dd span).text = example text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm not sure how to go about this, but to expand on the title, I have the following code:

```
<dl class="accordion">
    <dd>
        <a href="#panel1">March, 2014 <span>click to open</span>
        </a>
        <div id="panel1" class="content active">CONTENT HERE</div>
    </dd>
    <dd>
        <a href="#panel1">March, 2014 <span>click to open</span>
        </a>
        <div id="panel1" class="content">CONTENT HERE</div>
    </dd>
</dl>
```

I need something like this, which I took from this question: [if jQuery element hasClass() change different element link text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11659377/if-jquery-element-hasclass-change-different-element-link-text)

```
if ($('#people').hasClass('user_view_active')){
  $('.title').find("a").text('People'); 
}else{
  $('.title').find("a").text('Jobs'); 
}
```

I need it to say something more like this:

```
if ($('dd').hasClass('active')){
  $('dd').find("span").text('click to close'); 
}else{
  $('dd').find("span").text('click to open'); 
}
```

Is there anyway this code could be condensed? And how do I initialize it?

Thanks =)

---

Question answered by @ArunPJohny! Although ears are open for best practice and formatting tips so throw that my way please and I hope this will help someone!

```
<script>
    $(function ($) {
        $('dl.accordion').find('dd:first span.click').text('click to close');
        $('dl.accordion').on("click", "dd", function (event) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                $('dl.accordion dd.active span.click').text('click to close');
                $('dl.accordion dd:not(.active) span.click').text('click to open');
            }, 50);
        })
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to target each dd separately like

```
$('dd span').text(function () {
    return $(this).closest('dd').hasClass('active') ? 'click to close' : 'click to open';
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/b9HU6/)

In your case, if any of the `dd` has the class `active` you are changing the text of all `span` elements value.

---

Another way is to

```
$('dd.active span').text('click to close');
$('dd:not(.active) span').text('click to open');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/b9HU6/2/)

Comment: Thanks, well the .active value will only apply on <dd> elements that are "open", there's already a little JS going on in the background. But this code is much smaller any ways!

Comment: The .active class will only be on 1 item at a time. Can we just overwrite the existing text in span with the new class when the class is .active? Or maybe specify the text as being 'click to open' by default for "dd span" and then for "dd.active span" the text will be 'click to close'? I'm not very good with jQuery right now but it's fun to play with, if you tell me that what you have is the best way to go then we'll just go with that!

Comment: @mattroberts33 If the active class will be there only for 1 item then I think as you suggested.. make the default text as `'click to open'`, then use the single line script `$('dd.active span').text('click to close');`

Comment: Thanks! @ArunPJohny, do I need to initialize that somehow or can I just throw it in script tags?

Comment: just add it in your script tag... probably in a dom ready handler

Comment: So it should look like this? (check out the bottom of my question!) @ArunPJohny

Comment: what is happening... can you edit attached fiddles to recreate the case

Comment: Well, the script is working sorry, I don't know why it isn't working on my page - here is a test link if you want to take a look! www.mrobertsdesign.ca/g2drivers/ and the page I'm testing it on is Courses (Oshawa), so www.mrobertsdesign.ca/g2drivers/courses/oshawa.php (ignore the glitch in the nav lol)

Comment: @mattroberts33 try `$(function ($) {
    $(".accordion").on("click", "dd", function (event) {
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('dl.accordion dd.active span').text('click to close');
            $('dl.accordion dd:not(.active) span').text('click to open');
        }, 50);
    })
});`

Comment: That actually works perfectly, so there's just one problem now - the text doesn't change on the initial load up, so if I set the top dd as active, it won't see that until you click it and re-open. @ArunPJohny

Comment: @mattroberts33 Try `$(function ($) {
    $(".accordion").on("click", "dd", function (event) {
        $('dl.accordion').find('dd:first span').text('click to close');
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('dl.accordion dd.active span').text('click to close');
            $('dl.accordion dd:not(.active) span').text('click to open');
        }, 50);
    })
});`

Comment: Getting there, it still waits for me to click it to look for the active class though. What if we have 2 functions, a smaller one that looks for the initial active class on page load and applied the 'click to close' text to it, and another on click that toggles the click to close and click to open? @ArunPJohny

Comment: @ArunPJohny here, I just switched the 2 lines and it works perfectly!    $(function ($) {
  $('dl.accordion').find('dd:first span.click').text('click to close');
  $(".accordion").on("click", "dd", function (event) {
   setTimeout(function () {
    $('dl.accordion dd.active span.click').text('click to close');
    $('dl.accordion dd:not(.active) span.click').text('click to open');
   }, 50);
  })
 });

Comment: Hey @ArunPJohny, I realized something. I made a mistake in my explanation, the .active class is on the div, not dd. Can we edit the code to search for "dl.accordion dd div.active" and change the "dl.accordion dd a span.click" text? http://jsfiddle.net/b9HU6/9/

Comment: @ArunPJohny okay so now we just have to add the click function back, something like this (except mine obviously doesn't work) http://jsfiddle.net/b9HU6/17/ (I just used your code with an edit in the origonal click function you made)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51714/discussion-between-arun-p-johny-and-mattroberts33)